# Remove duplicity

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to a course of Angular with rxjs and our group have received a challenge.

They've sent us a chunk of code and said that althought it works fine, the code is not clean and the function "getUserLogin" has some duplicity in comparison with the "login" method. So, the challenge is to identify it and remove this duplicity.

Here is the code:

```
login(): Observable<UserModel> {
    if (!sessionStorage["userCredentials"]){
        return this.http.get<UserModel>(`${environment.apiLogin}/user/login?sistema=${enviroment.system}`,
        { withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(
            tap((res: UserModel) => {
                sessionStorage["userCredentials"] = JSON.stringify(res);
        })
        );
    } else {
        return Observable.of(<UserModel>JSON.parse(sessionStorage["userCredentials"]));
    }
}

getUserLogin(): Observable<string> {   
    if (sessionStorage["userCredentials"]){
        const userData = <UserModel>JSON.parse(sessionStorage["userCredentials"])
        return Observable.of(userData.login);
    }

    return Observable.of("");
}
```

Any help in solving this challenge would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the `getUserLogin()` need to return an Observable if both it's return statements use `Observable.of()`? Wouldn't it be simpler to return a plain string?

Comment: I’m also having trouble to understand that! Do you know some material for reading to understand better observable methods?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
login(): Observable<UserModel> {
    const cred = this.getUserCredentialsFromStorage();
    if (!cred){
        return this.http.get<UserModel>(`${environment.apiLogin}/user/login?sistema=${enviroment.system}`,
        { withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(
            tap((res: UserModel) => {
                sessionStorage["userCredentials"] = JSON.stringify(res);
        }));
    }
    return Observable.of(cred);
}

getUserCredentialsFromStorage(): UserModel {
  if (sessionStorage["userCredentials"]) {
      const userData = <UserModel>JSON.parse(sessionStorage["userCredentials"]);
      return userData;
  }
  return null;
}

getUserLogin(): Observable<string> {   
  const cred = getUserCredentialsFromStorage();
  return  Observable.of(cred ? cred.login : '');
}
```

Note that in refactoring this, you need to pay careful attention to types.

Both `getUserLogin` and `login` parse the sessionStorage object to get a `UserModel`, then do different things with it. One returns an `Observable<UserModel>` and the other extracts the login string and returns an `Observable<string>`. So we can refactor out a function that parses the `UserModel` and have both functions call that.

Comment: Thanks, man, your answer seems very good! If you don’t mind, a have a couple of questions. In “getUserCredentialsFromStorage”, why create a constant userData just to return it right away? Wouldn’t it be more economic to just return <UserModel>JSON.parse? And what’s the difference between Observale<UserModel> and Observable <string>? I’m having some trouble dealing with observables. Do you know any material that’s nice for reading and understanding that part?

Comment: Yes of course you could return the parse result right away. The difference between Observable<UserModel> and Observable<string> is that in the former case, consumers of the observable are receiving instances of a UserModel object, in the other simple strings (in this case the login field of UserModel). I have some familiarity with Angular but I'm no expert on it so can't point you in the direction of resources on Observables other than what you can no doubt google up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, the only thing I can infer is that there are duplicate checks for sessionStorage value in both the functions.

IMO below should be the revised code

```
login(): Observable<UserModel> {
        this.getUserLogin().mergeMap(res => {
            if (res === '') {
                return this.http.get<UserModel>(`${environment.apiLogin}/user/login?sistema=${enviroment.system}`,
                    { withCredentials: true })
                    .pipe(
                        tap((res: UserModel) => {
                            sessionStorage["userCredentials"] = JSON.stringify(res);
                            this.userData(sessionStorage["userCredentials"])
                        })
                    );
            } else {
                this.userData(sessionStorage["userCredentials"])
            }
        })

    }



    getUserLogin(): Observable<string> {
        if (sessionStorage["userCredentials"]) {
            this.userData(sessionStorage["userCredentials"])
        }

        return Observable.of("");
    }

    userData(data) {
        const userData = <UserModel>JSON.parse(data)
        return Observable.of(userData.login);
    }
```